# Create a new column based on difference of dates

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe in which I have to create a new column based on the difference of two dates. Example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  Date      New_Column_Required
 A    X    A   01/01/2001   Wave1
 B    Y    Q   01/01/2001   Wave1
 C    Z    N   01/01/2001   Wave1
 D    W    M   02/01/2001   Wave2
 E    Q    V   02/01/2001   Wave2
 F    R    O   03/01/2001   Wave3
 G    S    T   03/01/2001   Wave3
```

2nd date - 1st date should be wave 1, 3rd date - 2nd date Wave 2 and so on. The problem I'm facing is because of the multiple dates can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we could change `Date` to class `Date`, `arrange` them based on `Date` and subtract `Date` from the `first` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0("Wave", Date - first(Date) + 1))
  #OR
  #mutate(new_col = paste0("Wave", as.integer(as.factor(Date))))


#  Col1 Col2 Col3       Date new_col
#1    A    X    A 2001-01-01   Wave1
#2    B    Y    Q 2001-01-01   Wave1
#3    C    Z    N 2001-01-01   Wave1
#4    D    W    M 2001-01-02   Wave2
#5    E    Q    V 2001-01-02   Wave2
#6    F    R    O 2001-01-03   Wave3
#7    G    S    T 2001-01-03   Wave3
```

And the same logic in base R :

```
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df <- df[order(df$Date), ]
transform(df, new_col = paste0('Wave', Date - Date[1] + 1))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), Col2 = c("X", 
"Y", "Z", "W", "Q", "R", "S"), Col3 = c("A", "Q", "N", "M", "V", 
"O", "T"), Date = c("01/01/2001", "01/01/2001", "01/01/2001", 
"02/01/2001", "02/01/2001", "03/01/2001", "03/01/2001")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm. One small question though, my dates are in the gaps of 7. I mean it's weekly data so instead of getting wave1,wave2, etc. I'm getting wave1, wave8, wave 15, in difference of 7. Any thoughts on how to do this in the function? I know I can replace them using gsub or str_replace but was wondering if it possible to do it in the function itself.

Comment: @ShivamSarin Try my commented out version `mutate(new_col = paste0("Wave", as.integer(as.factor(Date))))`